# Where to find AWS Serverless database creation events in AWS EventBridge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

The closest I've gotten to an example was from ChatGPT so far:

```json
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
  "detail-type": "RDS Cluster Instance Creation Event",
  "source": "aws.rds",
  "account": "<ARN-ID>",
  "time": "2022-03-03T10:00:00Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:<ARN-ID>:cluster:dashboard-db-cluster-vegamx",
    "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:<ARN-ID>:db:dashboard-db-cluster-vegamx-instance"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "Event": "created",
    "DBInstanceIdentifier": "dashboard-db-cluster-vegamx-instance",
    "DBClusterIdentifier": "dashboard-db-cluster-vegamx",
    "Engine": "aurora-postgresql",
    "EngineVersion": "14.6",
    "InstanceClass": "db.serverless",
    "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
    "Status": "creating",
    "MultiAZ": false
  }
}
```

This is my Rule's `Event Pattern` that I'm trying to trigger:

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.rds"],
  "detail-type": ["RDS Cluster Instance Creation Event"],
  "detail": {
    "Event": ["created"],
    "DBInstanceIdentifier": [
      {
        "prefix": "dashboard-db-cluster"
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

I am able to test the event pattern in Event Bridge, However I am not able to see the actual event trigger the targeted lambda or anything under CloudWatch Logs.

[image: AWS EventBridge Rule Pattern Tester]

Comment: You mentioned Serverless database in title but rds is not a sever less db, are you sure event bus target has been configured? usually its sns or sqs and from there lambda

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because content from ChatGPT is currently banned here. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/14853083

Comment: @mikeumus, you also need to make sure that `CloudWatch Events needs permissions to send events to the target. ` so your iam role should have those permissions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-cloud-watch-events.html

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, we don't have to close the question. My event-pattern will not fire for any event so far, doesn't have to be the triggering words.

Comment: @Mikeumus Read the link I provided. ChatGPT is seriously unreliable for code generation and it's not considered a worthwhile use of resources to spend time debugging it.

Comment: I'm not trying to run it as code. I just wanted an example of an EventBridge event for an AWS Aurora Serverless db creation event and I couldn't find it online and didn't remember CloudTrail till @Sri reminded me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not seeing anything in the logs or lambda being triggered is because the event didn't match.

I understand that during your testing of the event it matches, however the actual events are very different to what you have been testing.

For Example:

**RDS DB Cluster Event**

```json
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "844e2571-85d4-695f-b930-0153b71dcb42",
  "detail-type": "RDS DB Cluster Event",
  "source": "aws.rds",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2018-10-06T12:26:13Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": ["arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24"],
  "detail": {
    "EventCategories": ["notification"],
    "SourceType": "CLUSTER",
    "SourceArn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24",
    "Date": "2018-10-06T12:26:13.882Z",
    "SourceIdentifier": "rds:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24",
    "Message": "Database cluster has been patched"
  }
}
```

**Event Pattern**

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.rds"],
  "detail-type": ["RDS DB Cluster Event"]
}
```

This is the actual event that gets logged under CloudTrail, so if you need anything specific or more, I recommend turning on CloudTrail and check out the event that gets generated and then use that event to create the EventBridge rule